# Active Record Updates or Deletes with LIKE sentences not working

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

When I'm performing an Update or Delete into my DDBB and I want to use a LIKE sentence, that is not taken into account, and only WHERE sentence is performed.

If I run the following query:

```
$this->db->or_like('title', 'name');
$this->db->where('id <=', 9823);
$this->db->update('tabla_name', $data);

var_dump( $this->db->last_query() );
```

I get the following query, where **no LIKE is applied**:

```
UPDATE `tabla_name` SET `field1` = 'value1', `field2` = 'value21' WHERE `id` <= '9823'
```

Same happens with DELETE clauses, when using **LIKE**, active record is not taken the LIKE filter into account. I used system core version 2.0.2, but I reproduced the same bug in 2.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while of research, I found in Ellislab forum the following solution:

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/99235/P15

Solution is not using `or_like` neither `like`, but only where sentences when performing an update or delete:

```
$this->DB->or_where( $field . ' like', '%' . $value . '%' );
$this->DB->where( $field . ' like', '%' . $value . '%' );
```